# Tabela não mostra linhas e nem colunas com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma table com bootstrap. Acontece que algumas coisas não funcionam.

1. O tamanho das TD's são sempre os mesmos.
2. Não consigo criar linhas para separar as linhas e colunas, como um grid.
3. Peguei uma opção de grid com bootstrap, mas da mesma forma não consigo criar linhas e colunas.

Abaixo meu código para construir a `table`:

```
<div id="tabela" class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Bairro</th>
                <th>Cidade</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Celular</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbcadastro">
            <tr>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>Endereço</td>
                <td>Bairro</td>
                <td>Cidade</td>
                <td>Estado</td>
                <td>Telefone</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ué, aqui abriu normal:
http://jsfiddle.net/aymone/4tfuL/

Comment: Sobre a 2, adicione a classe `table-bordered` na tabela. Confira a documentação: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: Já possui @Andrey...Olha o table Class, acho que o problema é outro, talvez o css dele misturando, algo assim.

Comment: Coloquei seu código para rodar e está rodando perfeitamente, o `css` e `js` do bootstrap estão realmente rodando? Também acho desnecessário o `border=0` na sua tabela.

Comment: Você tem outro arquivo css que está importando junto com o css do bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

O problema se deve ao fato de vc estar colocando

```
border=0
```

na definição da tabela. remova e verá o resultado!

se você está usando o bootstrap 3 fica fácil você controlar o tamanho das colunas 
usando as classes de grid ex: col-sm-2 por exemplo.

abuse dessas classes costumam ser muito úteis

Comment: o border=0 era apenas um teste com html puro. Sem ela também não funciona, fica tudo sem linhas delimitatórias das colunas.

Comment: qual versão do bootstrap?